# How to get the last row in the table using group by with Order by DESC?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have two tables,
table one name (**tbl_brands**) with these columns:

[image]

and second table name (**tbl_loader_attachment**) with these columns:

[image]

I used this MySQL code below to sort by DESC:

```
SELECT tbl_loader_attachment.*, tbl_brands.*  FROM tbl_loader_attachment
INNER JOIN tbl_brands ON(tbl_brands.b_id=tbl_loader_attachment.b_id)
GROUP BY tbl_loader_attachment.b_id ORDER BY tbl_loader_attachment.la_id DESC
```

When I execute my code select the first row appear (test1) I want to select the last row get (test4)

Comment: Please don't change the question after you have received multiple answers.  Doing so would invalidate all the work already done by those users who ventured an answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, thank you very much this is worked for me, but if I have an other table (**tbl_images**) when I used INNER JOIN appear duplicated brands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach uses a `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT tla1.*, tb.*
FROM tbl_brands tb
INNER JOIN tbl_loader_attachment tla1
    ON tb.b_id = tla1.b_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT b_id, MAX(la_id) AS max_la_id
    FROM tbl_loader_attachment
    GROUP BY b_id
) tla2
    ON tla1.b_id = tla2.b_id AND
       tla1.la_id = tla2.max_la_id;
```

If you are using MySQL 8+ (or should a future reader of this question be using MySQL 8+), then another option here is to use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b_id ORDER BY la_id DESC) rn
    FROM tbl_loader_attachment
)

SELECT tla.*, tb.*
FROM tbl_brands tb
INNER JOIN cte tla ON tb.b_id = tla.b_id
WHERE tla.rn = 1;
```

Comment: I have multiple brand name, when I used LIMIT get only one brands, this is no solution.

Comment: @Talib Sorry, your original question was not entirely clear to me, I have given you another option.

Comment: Thank you @Tim Biegeleisen, this is work for me, but I want to update my Question to three tables then please answer me

Comment: Well you would need to add another join.  The exact logic, and whether we need another subquery/CTE, would depend on your actual data.